# Java - JSF - metric to imperial unit, conversion using locale

Tags: java, jsf, localization, converters, distance

Is there a localization libary in Java for length distance values and units?

Similar to `SimpleDateFormat`?

Or is there a JSF component out there, since it often is just necessary for displaying purposes?

Comment: You mean, for converting between metric and imperial units?

Comment: Yes exactly. Something similar to the date converter. You give a base value in its si-unit, define its type (anything like metres, weight, temperature) and with a provided pattern you could convert it to your target unit. For example convert metres to foot and inches. `<f:convertMetric value="10" type="metres" pattern="f i">`. Or define also input and output type. Depends on how complex it should get. The class would simply be enough to create a el function out of it.

Comment: You could write a converter pretty easily. Since the default value is basically !inUnitedStates() it is a pretty simple check to see if you're using a metric system. The downside is that you're probably dealing with estimated values and accuracy. (You don't want to display 1.01m or 3.21' generally).

Comment: That "easily" depends on how much you wanna implement. Yep accuracy is also a good point. I am not really in a big need for it but just thought about it if its already available.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Units of Measurement API](https://code.google.com/p/unitsofmeasure/) respectively its implementations in the [JScience](http://jscience.org/) library.